# Geofence Server GUI different from docs

Tags: geoserver-geofence

As per the geoserver documentation, I have installed geoserver. I am using 2.13.0 version of geoserver and geofence server plugin downloaded from "nightly GeoServer community module builds" - http://ares.opengeo.org/geoserver/master/community-latest/ (version 2.13.0)

After installation , I checked for the geofence GUI in document which is different from the one I have installed. the image shown below is given in the docs.

[image]

http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geofence-server/gui.html

But , what I got is shown in the following image

[image]

Moreover, in the documentation, it is stated that in geofence rule, access type ACCESS can be selected.But I dint get that option in my access dropdown

[image]

1. Is there anything I have missed while installing or I have to install other than 'Geofence-Server-plugin' ?
2. The application is supposed to be as shown in the documentation. But why it is different ?

Comment: We are always seeking volunteers to update the documentation, please see http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/introduction/gettinginvolved.html for how you can update the documentation to match the latest version.